# Batch: Abrir una página web con los operadores de %variable% intermedios

Tags: windows, batch

Tengo un código en Batch, el cual quiero jugar directamente con a URL de una página de calculadora de tiempo.

He logrado identificar cuales son los valores que manda para realizar el cálculo.

Ya "funciona" a medias, he logrado colocar la fecha, el problema ahora son las horas.

El código que me interesa arreglar es el siguiente:

```
...sdatum=%dia_in%-%mes_in%-%anno_in%&szeit=02%3A12&typ=zeit...
```

Como se puede observar, están las variables `%dia_in%`, `%mes_in%`, `%anno_in%`

y donde `02%` sería la hora, `%3A12` serían los minutos

El problema vienen en la parte: `szeit=02%3A12&`

Ya que el " `%` " de este pedazo de código `02%3A12&` es parte de la página web, no es una variable.

Y al correrlo con el `start` aparece de la siguiente manera:

```
szeit=023A12&
```

Como se puede observar, se borra el `%` ya que Batch no sabe como interpretarlo y cree que es una variable (o al menos el inicio de una)

He intentado agregarlo a que sea parte de una cadena de texto como:

```
szeit=02"%"3A12&
```

o

```
szeit=02+"%"+3A12&
```

y no he podido.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que deberías poder escapar el caracter con el precediendolo del símbolo ^.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder utilizar el *%* en la cadena y diferenciar de una variable de entorno, entonces debes usar doble *%*, el caracter  *&* debe ir precedido por un *^* o en su defecto encierra entre comillas dobles todo la frase. Por ejemplo:

```
   set dia_in=13
   set mes_in=03
   set anno_in=2023

   echo ".sdatum=%dia_in%-%mes_in%-%anno_in%&szeit=02%%3A12&typ=zeit..."
   echo .sdatum=%dia_in%-%mes_in%-%anno_in%^&szeit=02%%3A12^&typ=zeit...
```

Resultarán en:

***".sdatum=13-03-2023&szeit=02%3A12&typ=zeit..."***

***.sdatum=13-03-2023&szeit=02%3A12&typ=zeit...***

**NOTA**

De acuerdo a la linea que pones en tu comentario, aquí algunas observaciones:

Como te mencioné, para el **%** debes poner dos **%%** y para **&** debes poner **^**: **^&**, aplicando esta regla a la linea que indicas en tu comentario, primero quitar todas las comillas porque no creo que formen parte de los parametros (y si forman parte del parametro le antecedes un ^) , donde hay un **&** puse delante de este un **^** de modo tal que quede **^&**, asi mismo, donde hay un **%** que no forma parte de una variable puse **%%**. Con estos cambios queda así:

```
set dia_fin=13
set mes_fin=03
set anno_fin=2023
set hor_fin=10

start topster.es/calendario/%%3A25^&typ=zeit^&edatum=%anno_fin%-%mes_fin%-%dia_fin%^&ezeit=%hor_fin%%%3A18^&subDazu=%%2B^&jahredazu=0^&wochendazu=0^&tagedazu=1^&zeitdazu=
```

Al ejecutar el bat, lo hace así:

```
start topster.es/calendario/%3A25&typ=zeit&edatum=2023-03-13&ezeit=10%3A18&subDazu=%2B&jahredazu=0&wochendazu=0&tagedazu=1&zeitdazu=
```

Por otro lado, como podrás observar a efectos de prueba le quité los tres puntos **...** que estában **/calendario/...**, supongo que ahi van algo mas que incluye inclusive el **?** que indica el inicio de los parametros. Si luego de esto no te funciona es porque lo que has puesto en lugar de los **...** tiene error. Acuerdate para **&** es **^&** y para **%** es **%%**. En este utlimo caso que importa que se junte con el **%** que le corresponde a una variable como en el caso de **%hor_fin%%%3A18**.

Guíate de esta parte que supongo que es el final de la linea:

```
^&typ=zeit^&edatum=%anno_fin%-%mes_fin%-%dia_fin%^&ezeit=%hor_fin%%%3A18^&subDazu=%%2B^&jahredazu=0^&wochendazu=0^&tagedazu=1^&zeitdazu=
```

Comment: No me funciona, sigue desapareciendo el % aún con los ^

No estoy imprimiendo con Echo,  estoy abriendo la página web con Start.

Comment: Puedes pines la linea completa que ewtas utilizando? El echo era como prueba que funciona. Si funciona con echo también debería funcionar para lo tuyo. Por favor pon el bat o la linea completa de como lo formas o disparas la página web

Comment: así lanzo el script:    start  https://www.topster.es/calendario/zeitrechner.php?styp=zeit"&"sdatum=%anno_in%-%mes_in%-%dia_in%"&"szeit=%hor_in%^%^3A25"&"typ=zeit"&"edatum=%anno_fin%-%mes_fin%-%dia_fin%^"&"ezeit=%hor_fin%%3A18^"&"subDazu=%2B"&"jahredazu=0"&"wochendazu=0"&"tagedazu=1"&"zeitdazu=

Comment: Puse una nota corrigiendo tu linea de comando

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió, eres un crack.